# javascript выдернуть время

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var offset = new Date ($('body').data('date'))* 1000
```

`offset` выводит 1508321154018

как выдернуть отсюда только часы и минуты ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто, используйте `toLocaleTimeString()`:

```js
var times = new Date(1508321154018).toLocaleTimeString();
console.log(times);
```

Comment: в поем случаи как ? var offset = new Date ($('body').data('date'))* 1000
на выходе этого кода получается 1508321154018

Comment: @gbrgbr как вы получаете дату ? $('body').data('date') - это что ? Старайтесь в вопросе приводить пример вашего кода

Comment: $('body').data('date') этот код выводит число 1508321154018

Answer (score 1):

[getHours](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours), [getMinutes](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMinutes)

```js
const date = new Date(1508321154018);
console.log(date.getHours(), date.getMinutes());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var offset = new Date ($('body').data('date'));
```

var times = new Date(offset).toLocaleTimeString();
console.log(times);